# Mutual Fund or Municipal Bond

Tags: united-states, mutual-funds, bonds, government-bonds, municipal-bonds

I am new to this Bond's so, I am not sure which one is a good investment like state or federal bonds? Is it worth to Invest now?

Comment: Before answering this, we need to know what your goal is?  (Are you a first time investor?  Diversify investments that are 100% stocks?  Heard about bonds, don't know what they are?  Etc, etc.)

Comment: Thanks @RonJohn for your comment. Lets say I have 100$ in my account and I am not a aggressive investor whats the best way to invest this 100$ apart from regular stocks so I can save some money from tax.

Comment: $100, or $100**K**?

Comment: Lets say1000$ roughly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both open-end mutual funds and ETF's are good choices for municipal bond investments.

However, if a leveraged investment is wanted in municipal bonds then there are closed-end mutual funds available.

A bad time to invest in bonds just involves looking for a short duration. A good time to invest in bonds involves looking for longer durations.

Some municipal bonds avoid both federal tax and state tax.

Comment: Can you share some good bond names

Comment: Any big name mutual fund or ETF is okay. There is a good list of closed-end funds at cefconnect.com and as listed under "Daily Pricing".

Answer (score 2):

> I am not sure which one is a good investment like state or federal bonds?

They're both safe.

> Is it worth to Invest now?

If for the long term, then yes, putting a portion (say 20%) of your investment fund in bonds is a good idea.

> Lets say1000$ roughly

You're pretty much stuck with bond funds.

> so I can save some money from tax.

Then you want either treasury bonds or **tax-free** municipal bonds from your state.